# Python/PyParsing: Difficulty with setResultsName

Tags: python, nlp, pyparsing

I think I'm making a mistake in how I call `setResultsName()`:

```
from pyparsing import *

DEPT_CODE = Regex(r'[A-Z]{2,}').setResultsName("Dept Code")
COURSE_NUMBER = Regex(r'[0-9]{4}').setResultsName("Course Number")

COURSE_NUMBER.setParseAction(lambda s, l, toks : int(toks[0]))

course = DEPT_CODE + COURSE_NUMBER

course.setResultsName("course")

statement = course
```

From IDLE:

```
>>> myparser import *
>>> statement.parseString("CS 2110")
(['CS', 2110], {'Dept Code': [('CS', 0)], 'Course Number': [(2110, 1)]})
```

The output I hope for:

```
>>> myparser import *
>>> statement.parseString("CS 2110")
(['CS', 2110], {'Course': ['CS', 2110], 'Dept Code': [('CS', 0)], 'Course Number': [(2110, 1)]})
```

Does `setResultsName()` only work for terminals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the definition of `course` to

```
course = (DEPT_CODE + COURSE_NUMBER).setResultsName("Course")
```

you get the following behavior:

```
x=statement.parseString("CS 2110")
print(repr(x))
# (['CS', 2110], {'Course': [((['CS', 2110], {'Dept Code': [('CS', 0)], 'Course Number': [(2110, 1)]}), 0)], 'Dept Code': [('CS', 0)], 'Course Number': [(2110, 1)]})
print(x['Dept Code'])
# CS
print(x['Course Number'])
# 2110
print(x['Course'])
# ['CS', 2110]
```

That's not exactly the `repr` you wanted, but does it suffice?

Note, [from the docs](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/python-pyparsing/htmldoc/pyparsing.pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setResultsName):

> [setResultsName] returns a *copy* of
>   the original ParserElement object;
>   this is so that the client can define
>   a basic element, such as an integer,
>   and reference it in multiple places
>   with different names.

So `course.setResultsName("Course")` does not work because it doesn't affect `course`. You would instead have to say `course=course.setResultsName("Course")`. That's an alternative way to do what I did above.

Comment: Also, it appears that `setResultsName()` returns a copy, but `setParseAction()` does not - why the inconsistency? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Rosarch: `repr()` returns a string representation of the object. It often gives a more complete view of the data inside an object than `str()`. I think you are right that `setParseAction` returns `self`, while `setResultName` returns a copy. I'm not knowledgable enough to explain why it is this way.